Iconify icons are not rendering
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/2.1.0/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span
        class="icon-[ph--airplay-fill]"
        style="width: 256px; height: 256px; color: #fff">
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I want the icon to be render in my html page. I am using the library for the first time. Please guide me what mistakes I am making in my code.

I got it working in other way if you look here.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/2/2.1.0/iconify.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span
        class="icon-[ph--airplay-fill]"
        style="display: block;width: 100px;height: 100px;">
      </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="iconify" data-icon="carbon:airplay-filled" data-inline="false" style="font-size: 48px;color: #ff5733;"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



